# Weird behavior with map.find and a pointer to a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, vector

I have a map of pairs to a vector of vectors that looks like this:

```
std::map<std::pair<uint16, uint16>, std::vector<std::vector<uint32> > >
```

The map is populated in the constructor of a class. This class provides a public method that returns a pointer to `std::vector<std::vector<uint32> >` (the map value part), with something like this:

```
typedef std::pair<uint16, uint16> key;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<uint32> > value;

value* FindValues(key someKey) {
    std::map<key, value>::const_iterator it;
    it = someStore.find(someKey);
    if (it != someStore.end()) 
        return &(value)it->second;
    return NULL;
}
```

This is when it gets weird. When iterating over the vector returned by FindValues, all child vectors have a large, negative number (such as -1818161232) as their first value. But if I use a function like:

```
value FindValues(key someKey) {
    std::map<key, value>::const_iterator it;
    return someStore.find(someKey)->second;
}
```

...then the value is normal. This only happens for the value at index 0 of **all** child vectors. With the second method, though, my application segfaults if a key wasn't found (for obvious reasons). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you cast `it->second` to `value` before you take the address?

Comment: @Kliest, I was going to ask the same thing.  Logically it shouldn't be a problem, but I'm always wary of `C`-style casts showing up when there are subtle and non-obvious problems.

Comment: Isn't the result of a cast an rvalue?

Comment: @Chad: It should be a problem simply because it won't compile. It is illegal to apply the built-in `&` operator to a result of a cast to a non-reference type. Such casts produce rvalues. Built in unary `&` requires lvalue.

Comment: What compiler are you using that accepts `return &(value)it->second;` without an error?

Comment: gcc 4.6.1 compiles this with a warning.

Comment: @Kleist: He's doing it because he used `const_iterator` for the search. For this reason `return &it->second` simply doesn't compile. So, he decided to "override" the error with that cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the return statement truly looks as

```
return &(value) it->second;
```

then there are several things that can be said about it:

1. Your compiler is broken if it accepts it without issuing diagnostic messages. In C++ it is illegal to apply built-in unary `&` to a result of non-reference cast. The `(value) it->second` expression produces a temporary object, an rvalue. You can't obtain the address of such object by using `&`. The code should not even compile.
2. If your compiler accepts it as some kind of weird "extension", then it means that you are indeed obtaining and returning the address of a *temporary object*. The temporary object is then immediately destroyed, leaving your pointer pointing to garbage. No wonder you see some weird values through such pointer.
3. The need for some sort of cast arises from the fact that you used `const_iterator` to store the result of the search. Apparently you made a misguided attempt to cast away constness of `it->second` with your `(value)` cast. The correct way to do it might look as follows

   ```
    return const_cast<value *>(&it->second);
   ```

   But why did you use `const_iterator` in the first place? The right thing to do would be to use a regular `iterator` and just do

   ```
    return &it->second;
   ```

   without any extra casts.
4. You need to decide what kind of `FindValue` method you are trying to write. If this is supposed to be a constant method, it should return `const value *` and should be declared as `const`

   ```
   const value* FindValues(key someKey) const
   ```

   and, of course, you should use `const_iterator` inside in this case.

   If your `FindValue` is supposed to be a non-constant method, then you can keep the current declaration

   ```
   value* FindValues(key someKey)
   ```

   but use ordinary `iterator` inside.

   What you have now is some sort of hybrid of the two, which is what makes you to resort to weird casts. (In fact, you will probably need both versions in your class. One can be implemented through the other.)

Answer (score 3):

Your `typedef`s are quite misleading. This is the erroneous line:

```
return &(value)it->second;
```

What appears to be a simple C-style type cast is actually a call to `std::vector`'s copy constructor. This line could be rewritten as

```
return &std::vector<std::vector<uint32> >(it->second)
```

The reason for the weird results become visible when you rewrite this line as following:

```
std::vector<std::vector<uint32> > result (it->second);
return &result;
```

You are actually returning the address of a local object that will be destroyed as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Its ok to have a non-const `value *`, as modifying the values won't affect the keys...

Comment: My mistake, you're right. Of course values may be modified safely.I was confused by another user proposing a `const_cast` instead of a C cast.

Answer (score 0):

So, this variant will be better.

```
typedef std::pair<uint16, uint16> key;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<uint32> > value;

value* FindValues(key someKey) {
    std::map<key, value>::const_iterator it;
    it = someStore.find(someKey);
    if (it != someStore.end()) 
        return &const_cast<value&>(it->second);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use a `const_iterator` if you're just going to cast away the const -- why not use `iterator` instead?  If `someStore` is const, then trying to modify the value is going to cause problems in any case -- you should have `FindValues` return a `const value *` in that case (and again, don't need the const_cast)